# Querying JSON with SelectTokens

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to query a `JArray` and get back another `JArray` based on some conditions. Now using LINQ I can first query it, return an `IEnumerable<JToken>` and convert it to another `JArray` like this:

```
IEnumerable<JToken> ienmTotalObjects = arrResults.Where(x => x["uResultId"]?.ToString() == arrTaskResults[intResult]["uResultId"].ToString() && x["iElementId"]?.ToString() == strUniqueElementId);
JArray arrTotalObjects = new JArray(ienmTotalObject);
```

Now I just came to know about the JSON.NET `SelectTokens`(https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) and seems like a pretty handy feature to query without converting to IEnumerable, However I'm unable to find a way to apply it in my case scenarios. Curious if it it is really possible ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?  Can you provide a sample [mcve] showing what you want to match?

Comment: @dbc something like this: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=687dd987fa2bd1e253bbe57599be5a1f

Comment: @BrianRogers please see this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question I can guess the 2 strcutures of `arrResults` and `arrTaskResults`

```
var arrResults = JArray.Parse(@"[
{ iElementId: 1, ""uResultId"" :""aa"" },
{ iElementId: 2, ""uResultId"" :""bb"" }
]");

var arrTaskResults = JArray.Parse(@"[
{ ""uResultId"" :""aa"" },
{ ""uResultId"" :""bb"" }
]");
```

However, I have no idea what `intResult` and `strUniqueElementId` are so these are set here

```
var intResult = 0;
var strUniqueElementId = "1";
```

We can now do the same queries but using SelectToken method passing in a JPath:

```
var s = arrTaskResults.SelectToken($"$[{intResult}].uResultId");

var selectTokens = arrResults.SelectTokens($"$[?(@.uResultId=='{s}' && @.iElementId=={strUniqueElementId})]");
```

Executing this will output the following:

```
[
  {
    "iElementId": 1,
    "uResultId": "aa"
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry but i'm not quite familiar with querying with the JPath things.. could you afford to explain please(the syntaxes and how it works)?

Comment: It's very similar to XPath (but for json) this might help - http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/